# Android LoaderManager Callbacks

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

Hi I'm using the onLoadFinished callback to set some variables

```
public class MainActivity 

...

double foo;

...

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Table.Field);
                double value = cursor.getDouble(index);
                if (lat > 0)
                    **foo = value;**
             }

        }
```

but, when I try to use this variable it seems like it is unset.

What am I doing wrong?

Should I synchronize this method with the main thread?

P.D 
The cursor does have data.

Comment: have you checked the onLoadFinished method is actually called. Add a Log.d("LoaderCallBack", "onLoadFinished invoked"); as first line of the method and check.

Comment: dump the Cursor then,  what do you see?

Comment: I checked and the onLoadFinished method is called.

Answer (score 0):

The MainActivity class has to implement the LoaderCallbacks interface like

```
public class MainActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

then you should provide that instance as parameter to the initLoader method